# Go to next step after submitting custom form in Magento 2 checkout

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, checkout

I created a module to add a new step to the Magento 2 checkout. This step has a custom form. On submitting the form I can't figure out how to go the the next step.

*checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <!-- The new step -->
                                    <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">/BB_CheckoutStep/js/view/my-step-view</item>

                                        <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                        <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                        <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!--add here child component-->

                                            <!--start of custom form-->
                                            <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">BB_CheckoutStep/js/view/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-container</item>
                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">BB_CheckoutStep/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                </item>

                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="text_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately) -->
                                                                    <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.text_field</item>
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Text Field</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="checkbox_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                    <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkbox_field</item>
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkbox Field</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="select_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                    <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
                                                                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
                                                                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
                                                                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <!-- value element allows to specify default value of the form field -->
                                                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.select_field</item>
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Field</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="date_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                    <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/date</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.date_field</item>
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Date Field</item>
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>

                                         <!--end of custom form-->

                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

*my-step-view.js*

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     *
     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
     * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
     *
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'BB_CheckoutStep/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'step_code',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Birthdate',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                9
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {
        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

*mystep.html*

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
```

```
<div id="checkout-step-title"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-container') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

*custom-checkout-form.js*

```
/*global define*/
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function(Component) {
'use strict';
return Component.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        // component initialization logic
        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Form submit handler
     *
     * This method can have any name.
     */
    onSubmit: function() {
        // trigger form validation
        this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
        this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');

        // verify that form data is valid
        if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
            // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
            var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
            // stepNavigator.next();
            // do something with form data
            console.dir(formData);
            this.navigateToNextStep();
        }
    }
});
});
```

custom-checkout-form.html

```
<div>
<form id="custom-checkout-form" class="form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: onSubmit" class="action">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Submit'"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

So i'm trying to use navigateToNextStep() from my-step-view.js in custom-checkout-form but i'm not sure on how to reference that. I also looked into giving parameters to getRegion. I just started working with Magento 2 and KnockoutJS so i'm sorry if it's a bit of a dumb question. I created the new step and custom form by following the Magento 2 Dev Docs. Thanks in advance :)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add stepNavigator as a parameter in custom-checkout-form.js.

```
/*global define*/
define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
  'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function(Component, stepNavigator) {
'use strict';
return Component.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        // component initialization logic
        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Form submit handler
     *
     * This method can have any name.
     */
    onSubmit: function() {
        // trigger form validation
        this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
        this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');

        // verify that form data is valid
        if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
            // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
            var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
            // do something with form data
            console.dir(formData);
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you help me I want to add custom dropdown on my checkout page?